# Avada migration urls not replaced

Tags: wordpress

When I have transfered the avada theme I have some errors to do with the locahost settings cause I build the site locally and then transfered.

```
Access to Font at 'http://localhost:8081/crescent/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff' from origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://localhost:8081/crescent/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf' from origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://localhost:8081/crescent/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://localhost:8081/crescent/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0' from origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://localhost:8081/crescent/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0' from origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://localhost:8081/crescent/wp-content/plugins/fusion-builder/inc/lib/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://crescent.solitudesoftware.co.uk' is therefore not allowed access.
```

However I cannot find where these are being stored to change the settings to the new url I have tried a replace plugin but its not picked the items up some reason.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue, it is a cache that is created by Avada theme.

To fix it reset the CSS and JS dynamic caches:

Avada > Theme Options > Advanced > Dynamic CSS & JS > Reset Fusion Caches

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaCVJ.png)

Comment: this option can now be found under Theme Options > Performance

Answer (score 1):

Per this post: https://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/are-your-font-awesome-icons-or-custom-fonts-not-showing-up/

You can add to your HTACCESS:

```
# Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

I had the same issue for a migrated site, but was unable to determine a location in the DB where the old URL persisted. The HTACCESS fix isn't as desirable as actually resolving the bad record; however, it works!

Answer (score 1):

I recently switched a clients site to a new domain that is using Avada theme and all the icomoon fonts disappeared. I tried editing .htaccess as some threads suggested...no dice!  Resetting the fusion caches worked like a charm.